# How do I unlock Dragonetti/Honeycoupe in Mario Kart Wii?

Tags: mario-kart-wii

Some time ago I went over to my friend's house. He had a kart called 'Dragonetti'. I like the statistics so I want to unlock it. How do I?

Answer (score 2):

## Steps:

1. Beat the 150CC Lightning Cup
2. Done, it should be unlocked for use

---

## Notes:

- It is called Dragonetti in PAL Regions, while being called Honeycoupe in NTSC Regions
- It can only be used for heavy-weight characters, such as King Boo, Dry Browser etc

---

## Source

[Mario Kart Wiki: Honeycoupe](http://mariokartwii.wikia.com/wiki/Honeycoupe)